# Why am I getting a null pointer exception here?

Tags: java

I am using java. The second line of this code is getting a null pointer exception.

```
double gpa = 0.0;
gpa = grads[index].calculateGPA();
return gpa;
```

grads is an array of Graduate objects. I have tested this method in a JUnitTest and it works fine. I have also tested calculateGPA(). Only when I run the program there is an error.

Comment: How is the `grads` array initialized?

Comment: Have you checked the value of `index` and `grads[index]` when you get the exception or simply tried running it in the debugger?

Comment: If you get an exception like this, your first step should be to add `System.out.println("grads is null: " + (grads == null) + " grads[index] is null: " + (grads[index] == null));` On the line before which the exception was thrown.

Comment: @Alderath thank you. I used your advice and discovered index was the problem

Answer (score 6):

The error could be caused by one of the following possibilities:

1. `grads` is `null`.
2. `index` is `null`.
3. `grads[index]` is `null`.
4. `calculateGPA()` is raising a null pointer exception.

Use your debugger to find out which of these possibilities it is, and take it from there.

Comment: Or the `grads` array as a whole is `null` (not initialized).

Comment: Or `index` is an `Integer` and is null.

Comment: OK, we are up to 4 candidates now. Any advance on 4?!  ;-)